# Managed path as reserved word for new Apps

Tags: document-library, managed-path

Has anyone come across of the "Reserved" word "unexpected error popup" when trying to add a Document library with the name identical to existing managed path?

For example, let's say I have a managed path "Sales". When trying to add up a Document Library with the name "Sales" (user's requirement)  I'd get this kind of an error resulting in the library not created.

I understand that the way around would be changing the library name, however, I've been puzzled with not founding this particular restriction in any documentation...

Thanks in advance for any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Managed Path words in the Site, subsite, list or libraries. I agree with you that documentation did not mentioned list/ libraries but once you create a managed path then it become a reserved words which cant be used inside the url.

here is the error in the uls logs when you try to create the library using the reserved word.

> Application error when access /_layouts/15/new.aspx, Error="Sites"
>   cannot be used as a site name. Site names cannot contain certain
>   reserved words and cannot begin with an underscore. Please enter a
>   different name.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateListFromRpc(NameValueCollection
>   queryString, Uri& nextUrl)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewListPage.BtnOk_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs args)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)